# Trying to print an unsigned long, but getting a different number

Tags: c, long-integer, primitive-types

I have a simple C program. I am trying to print the number **1528108405744583338**.

Here is the simple code I have;

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long number = 1528108405744583338;
    printf("%lu", number );
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, on the console I get the output as **2930885290**. What's going on in here ? I tried it on Dev-C++, C-Free 5.0 environments, but got the same result in both. I checked similar posts, and tried the solution ways but that answers could not help me to solve my problem. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value in question required a 64-bit datatype, and an `unsigned long` is not necessarily 64 bits.  It is guaranteed to be at least 32 bits.  So if your system uses 32-bits for `unsigned long` you'll get the value you got, and if it uses  64-bits for `unsigned long` you'll get the expected value.

An `unsigned long long` is guaranteed to hold this value, so use that instead.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long long number = 1528108405744583338ULL;
    printf("%llu", number );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @OzanYurtsever Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: The `LL` suffix is not needed here.